# Cannot install pymssql on windows

Tags: python, freetds, python-3.5, pymssql

i am trying to install pymssql as

```
pip install pymssql
```

i have windows 7 and python 3.5 (from anaconda) but i get

```
Failed building wheel for pymssql
```

i believe its related to `freetds` and `python-dev`. how do i install these on windows?

Which packages would i need to install? this pip install worked just fine for python 2.7. If the pip does not work,is there any other way i can download and install pymssql?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv on Windows?

Comment: no, i am not running a virtual environment

Comment: On my Win7 64 machine, with Python 3.5 (installed via installer, not anaconda), I can install pymssql just fine (latest version, 2.1.2). However, I have virtualenvwrapper-win installed, which may include a working version of wheel. Perhaps try `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win` first?

Comment: the program cant start because vcruntime140.dll is missing from your computer. try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Comment: I'm out of my depth here, but are you an admin on the machine? Maybe try the install package instead of anaconda?

Comment: turns out the problem was twofold. i did not have the admin rights plus my pip version was outdated. running the cmd as admin and updating the pip allowed me to install pymssql !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just went through this small bit of hell and finally got things working, here is what I ended up doing:

First locate your Python directory (for me it was `c:\Python35`), then following the instructions found on the [PyMSSQL documentation](http://www.pymssql.org/en/latest/freetds.html#windows) download the [FreeTDS binaries](https://github.com/ramiro/freetds/releases) and the [precompiled OpenSSL binaries](http://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-openssl/).  Open SSL binaries are built in different versions of MSVC, for me I needed the MSVC 2015 32-bit binaries (because my copy of Python is the 32-bit build).  FreeTDS is a little more cryptic, here the different `vs20xx` versions work with different generations of Python, in my case `-vs2015` worked because I am using Python 3.5 which should work for you as well.

Next extract the dlls from the '/bin' directory in the OpenSSL release and the `/lib` directory in the FreeTDS release into a folder (in my case I used `c:\Python35\FreeTDS`).

Finally add this folder to your system `PATH`.  You can now run `import pymssql` and not receive any errors.  On windows you can also create a [config file](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm) located at `C:\freetds.conf` which can provide some global settings to keep your python scripts clear of any connection strings.

Comment: Instead of fiddling with the `PATH` I also had success putting the required files into the `site-packages` folder.

Comment: @Crazometer that would also work. The path suggestion came from the FreeTDS documentation (I think because there are some command line utilities included in the distribution)