# Error while installing pymssql on windows 10

Tags: python-3.5, pymssql

I'm getting "The system cannot find the path specified" error.

Could anyone give me some hint about how to make the path correct?

I've never encountered this type of error before while I'm using pip.

```
    C:\Users\ahkim>pip install pymssql
Collecting pymssql
  Downloading pymssql-2.1.3.tar.gz (897kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 901kB 1.9MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: pymssql
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pymssql ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Users\ahkim\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ahkim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-mfok55b5\\pymssql\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\ahkim\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp127kpd9epip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  setup.py: platform.system() => 'Windows'
  setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building '_mssql' extension
  error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pymssql
  Running setup.py clean for pymssql
Failed to build pymssql
Installing collected packages: pymssql
  Running setup.py install for pymssql ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\ahkim\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ahkim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-mfok55b5\\pymssql\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ahkim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-r247wrkl-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Windows'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    cythoning _mssql.pyx to _mssql.c
    warning: _mssql.pyx:143:4: Exception already a builtin Cython type
    building '_mssql' extension
    error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\ahkim\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ahkim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-mfok55b5\\pymssql\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ahkim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-r247wrkl-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ahkim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mfok55b5\pymssql\
```

Comment: pymssql 2.1.3 has pre-built wheel files for Python 3.5, so it's odd that pip would try building it from source. You could try downloading the appropriate wheel file from PyPI (for [64-bit Python](https://pypi.python.org/packages/b2/25/b60fd3fe28f7102b8880078ca3c5ce8faac82e2d402ed943048f80ef57ad/pymssql-2.1.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl#md5=c4619627135530e9a31c8c8d4ed92e84) or [32-bit Python](https://pypi.python.org/packages/b4/aa/9578d384a4b0bbdcb3df66bb874d62e26d6a817c4f799a054351af76aeee/pymssql-2.1.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl#md5=5d202fbaf25eb81ee3a2ebc1b79cd327)) and try installing that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install pymssql on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303462/cannot-install-pymssql-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

look this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pymssql-python-development

For choose right file to download you must determine number of cp 
 Ex : cp27 , cp36 and so on

```
import pip
print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
```

like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hijmU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Person who using Python through anaconda, should run below code in anaconda command line, as admin.

**conda install pymssql.**

I have testing and worked fine, this will take roughly 20-30 mins while it will also install all other dependencies.